# Solvable polynomial by radicals

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $f(x) ∈ Q[x]$ be a polynomial of degree $≤ 8$ and satisfying $f(−x) = f(x)$. Prove that
>   $f(x)$ is solvable by radicals.

Comment: $f$ is a polynomial in $x^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is a degree $\leq 4$ polynomial in $t:=x^2$. So the Galois group of $f(t)$ over $\mathbb Q$ is a subgroup of $S_4$, and is therefore solvable, so $f(t)$ is solvable by radicals. Then solving $x^2=t$ is still using radicals.

Comment: we don't have to discuss whether f irreducible or not?

Comment: Well if $f(t)$ is reducible then we can just study its irreducible components, but the degrees of these components will also be $\leq 4$.

Comment: Otherwise said : there is a theorem saying that all equations $P=0$  with $deg P \leq 4$ are solvable by radicals.